# Does pausing an AdWords campaign and splitting it into two new campaigns cause problems?

Tags: google, advertising, google-ads, conversions, campaigns

I have been using AdWords for one year. It was going smoothly and we were receiving good result from AdWords.

Two months ago we rearranged the AdWords for better optimization by pausing the campaign which we had been using for a long time and created two more campaigns that arranged the keywords hoping for better results.  We didn't change anything other than separating the campaigns. Since then we have not been receiving no inquiries for our firm from the ads.  Even after waiting for two months, there has been no improvement.

Are there known problems with pausing a working campaign and splitting it into two new campaigns?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does affect the performance big time. There are various reasons for this to happen, like check for the keywords that assisted the conversions of other keywords based on impressions.
Pausing those keywords which assisted the conversions might give you a hard time getting any inquiries. Your campaign budgets, Device bids, ads for those keywords also play a crucial role in account performance.

Comment: Apart from splitting, we have "not changed anything". Then how did this happen. Please give little more explain.

Comment: How long will it takes to back to normal?

Comment: Have you visited kerala any time?